# How to connect Oracle 11g with nodejs in Windows?

Tags: oracle, node.js

I want to be able to use nodejs to connect to Oracle 11g database. I have only seen connectivity with 9i, though would like to know how to be able to use it under a Windows environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Module [oracle](https://npmjs.org/package/oracle) is the most updated and feature rich Oracle driver in npm. It supports 11g version as well.

Answer (score 1):

1. install required tools

   1. VS2012(express edition as well, I choosed this)
   2. python2.7(add to path)
   3. nodejs
   4. Oracle11g
2. add the oracle driver to system environment path:

   OCI_LIB_DIR=C:\oracle\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\oci\lib\msvc
   OCI_INC_DIR=C:\oracle\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\oci\include
3. `npm install oracledb`

Then you can connect oracle with nodejs.

My OS is Win8 64bit.

[Source : github node-oracledb](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/INSTALL.md#instwin)

Answer (score 0):

If you are comfortable in C#, an option is to call .NET in-process and leverage .NET's mature database ecosystem. Refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33005452/30246).