# Connect Node.js with Oracle on Windows platform

Tags: windows, oracle, node.js

I have oracle 11g and I am running Windows 7. I have setup node.js and it's working perfectly fine with MongoDB and other stuff. I have a couple of tools to build for my team, and I wanted to use this opportunity to learn Node.js. But the problem is that the database is oracle and I am so tired of trying to make it work, so tired that I created a stackoverflow account. I did read many of the questions posted without finding an answer how to set this up properly on Windows.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, it is always a good idea to show some initiative before asking a question here so tell us - what have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried node packages that allow you to connect to Oracle DB. Here are some :

1. oracle [npm page](https://npmjs.org/package/oracle) and [Github](https://github.com/nearinfinity/node-oracle)
2. db-oracle [npm page](https://npmjs.org/package/db-oracle) and [Github](https://github.com/mariano/node-db-oracle)

To install do this

```
npm install oracle //or
npm install db-oracle
```

Comment: Currently, it does not work with windows without some additional workarounds. See https://github.com/nearinfinity/node-oracle/issues/2

Answer (score 0):

[db-oracle](https://npmjs.org/package/db-oracle) does not work on windows due to a dependency on the unix "pthread.h" library.

The [oracle](https://npmjs.org/package/oracle) library is now reported to work on Windows, but requires having a suitable C++ compiler installed (e.g., VisualStudio).

Answer (score 0):

There is a new Oracle provided node module that just got released.
Check it out: https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/

Here is Oracle's announcement:
https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/entry/introducing_node_oracledb_a_node

In the announcement, they claim to be making it Windows compatible soon.