# AngularJS and Visual Studio

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio-2013, angularjs-e2e

Is there an option to use AngularJS and all its features (including unit testing feature) in Visual Studio, without having NodeJS installed?

Apart from this, is there any Visual Studio template/extension for AngularJS?

Thanks and regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look at [NTVS](https://nodejstools.codeplex.com/), you would have to just install node.js to use this in visual studio, but running, debugging, testing all can be run from visual studio only.also you can host this using IIS as well (though this has nothing to do with NVTS).

**EDIT**

finally came up with even better solution, it doesnt need NTVS and can work with any VS version

have a look at my answer to my own question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22115182/how-to-combine-these-angularjs-visual-studio-nodejs)

Comment: Thanks. I think this one is a better fit option. :)

Comment: But please let me know if there is any more better solution to this.

Comment: @TempOrary have a look at my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22115182/how-to-combine-these-angularjs-visual-studio-nodejs), I finally came up with a better solution

Answer (score 0):

You can install Angular as a nuget package. When it comes to testing it's a little more complicated. You can read this http://codeforcoffee.org/setting-up-angular-js-jasmine-and-karma-in-visual-studio/

Comment: Thanks. But this still has a NodeJS dependency. I am looking for a way without NodeJS.