# nodejs_'npm install oracle' occur errors

Tags: node.js, python-2.7, node-oracledb

I've got errors when install oracle on nodejs.
I'm following the steps written in this site (https://github.com/joeferner/node-oracle) and
finally, 'npm install oracle' doesn't work.

I downloaded python2.7.8, visual studio express 2012 for desktop, and instantclient (basic and sdk)
in the same directory named "Project" and also set environment variables in my laptop.

Here is the errors occurred.

```
C:\dev\Project>npm install oracle
npm WARN package.json Express-web-app@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN package.json Express-web-app@1.0.0 No repository field
npm WARN package.json fs@0.0.2 fs is also the name of a node core module.
npm WARN package.json fs@0.0.2 fs No description
npm WARN package.json fs@0.0.2 fs No repository field
-
> oracle@0.3.7 install C:\dev\Project\node_modules\oracle
> node-gyp rebuild


C:\dev\Project\node_modules\oracle>node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python2.7.8", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at failNoPython (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:103:14)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:64:11
enter code here
gyp ERR! stack     at Object.oncomplete (evalmachine.<anonymous>:107:15)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
gyp ERR! command "node" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\dev\Project\node_modules\oracle
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.32
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v1.0.1
gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! oracle@0.3.7 install: 'node-gyp rebuild'
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the oracle@0.3.7 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the oracle package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls oracle
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "oracle"
```

I don't know the reason why errors say 'Can't find python executable.....brr' ...

Answer (score 1):

try setting the python system variable use this tutorial:
http://www.katsbits.com/tutorials/blender/python-path-variable.php

Comment: well,I can't understand now.I already set the system variable and the path is also correct. :(

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're running on Windows.

Please see my comment at https://github.com/joeferner/node-oracle/issues/140#issuecomment-67266788
if it will work. Got mine working using that method. However, since your not using Ubuntu Server x64 14.10 LTS.

#### You may need to convert /etc/environment to Windows Path.

Try installing on a Virtual Machine to run node apps on a much more community driven support environment OS.

If you decided running instantclient on Ubuntu I have used this guide for installing instantclient and compiling oci8 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PHPOracle

I made a gist for this.
https://gist.github.com/ChaosPower/e533c0542ad0def26cfb

Please inform me if it works and if not let me try to replicate yours.

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install npm@install
```

It is showing an error because It might be possible that you haven't installed NPM latest version.

Answer (score -1):

Not a direct answer to your q, but if you are comfortable in C#, an alternate option is to call .NET in-process and leverage .NET's mature database ecosystem. Refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33005452/30246).

Comment: Will give this a try.